# ActiveRecord query from an array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array of hash.

```
eg) array_of_hash = [ { id: 20, name: 'John' }, { id: 30, name: 'Doe'} ]
```

I would like to get records which match all the criteria in a particular hash.
So the query I want to get executed is

```
SELECT persons.* FROM persons WHERE persons.id = 20 AND persons.name = 'John' OR persons.id = 30 AND persons.name = 'Doe'
```

What is the best way to construct this query from an array of hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is okay:

```
ids = array_of_hash.map { |h| h[:id] }
names = array_of_hash.map { |h| h[:name] }

Person.where(id: ids, name: names)
```

(although it's not super generic)
other attempt:

```
people = Person.all
array_of_hash.each do |h|
  people = people.where(h)
end
people # => will generate a long long query.
```

Comment: How to eliminate
 
`{ id: 20, name: 'Doe' }` ?

Comment: I think the OP wants something like ((id1 and name1) or (id2 and name2)), doesn't he?

Comment: This might return records with id - 20 and name - 'Doe'. I want records which match all the conditions in a particular hash.

Comment: I assume that `id` is your primary key. so this doesn't matter, you'll get the same results.

Comment: At first glance this looked like what I wanted. But chaining the where method _ands_ the condition inside the where clause.

Comment: Are you using rails 5.0?

Comment: No, I am using 4.2.6

Answer (score 0):

Try to map all conditions to your ActiveRecord model independently and flatten the result array afterwards:

```
array_of_hash.map{ |where_clause| Person.where(where_clause) }.flatten
```

Comment: How would you flatten an array of `ActiveRecord::Relation`s

Comment: Wouldn't this run a query for every single where clause? I would prefer if all the records can be loaded in a single query.

Comment: @RaVeN You can, just verified it here. `ActiveRecord::Relation` becomes a normal array automatically. I don't think a downvote is appropriate here.

Comment: But the n+1 problem is still here ;)

Comment: @LarsonB Yes, this approach uses n queries, depending on your array length.

Comment: @RaVeN Of course, if performance is critical and the array can be large a more advanced approach should be taken. This is one is just the simple and obvious one.